# Neighbours guttering running onto roof

Tags: roofing, gutters

Hi I have just got home to see our neighbour at the back has put guttering running straight onto our outhouse roof. I wondered if this was allowed or should the pipe be going right down to the guttering below? I'm worried this will cause a leak in the roof if we get heavy rain?[image] Any help appreciated

Comment: Not sure how your laws work, but I'd be dubious that it's legit for them to run their gutter onto your roof, rather than keeping it on their side of the line, wherever the line is here. Can you [edit] to clarify where the ownership changes precisely? Are we seeing 2, 3, 4 properties intersectiong here?

Comment: It's common that an upper level gutter doesn't connect directly to a gutter on a lower roof section which is collected by the subsequent gutter. It is uncommon for houses to be that close in my area, and you are not allowed to divert water runoff to a neighbors property so I can't answer that part.

Comment: That does look like a particularly British type of architectural… inventiveness. If the property all belonged to a single owner, the only worry I would have (apart from that outhouse roof needs attention anyway) is how large an area the upper section serves. If that's from an entire 'house-sized' roof it could run pretty fast in heavy rain, causing over-spill. (Legally, I don't know, but we share one downpipe with our neighbours just because it works best that way.)

Comment: Sorry to make it clearer the small roof in the foreground is our property, the red brick wall behind is the neighbours property backing onto it and the mid-level one to the right is next doors. The gutting they have coming onto our roof is channeled from their main roof at the top of the photo and also a conservatory roof to the right